# Opencart theme z-index

Tags: jquery, css, themes, opencart

I have a problem with my theme on opencart (latest version). It looks like this (first pic). When I open the basket, it goes like this, under the slideshow bellow (second pic). I don't understand why it goes under it, because it should stay above and look like this (3rd pic).

I've tried something with z-index ... but it didn't work.
I'm looking for your answers

Pics here: http://www.yogile.com/lr32tdv5/41m/share/?vt=ya53LCf

Comment: You should provide some of the codes which you are working on for more details.

Comment: Http://decoded.ro/oc/ - here is the address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index requires certain things to work. First, you need to create a stacking context on an element that is a "root" of both elements that need re-ordered. You can create a stacking context by adding `position: relative;`. in css (or use something in [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)).

Then add a z-index to each branch off the root that needs to be set. and give them `position: absolute | relative;`. For example, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fy1rccm/

**edit:**
Given the website you linked, it works if you add

```
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
```

to the role=banner css class.

and

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

to the container css class.

And I encourage you to read the first link I posted, lots of good stuff on stacking contexts in there without being too long or boring.